# Access VB connect with oracle database

Tags: vba, oracle, ms-access

I was trying to connect a remote Oracle database in Access2016 VBA with the following code:

```vb
Public Sub OpenConn()

Dim adConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim myDSN As String

Set adConn = New ADODB.Connection

myDSN = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;DSN=111.111.111.11:1521/orcl;USER ID=xxxx;PASSWORD=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True"

adConn.Open myDSN

end sub
```

But it did not work and gave a

> 'run time error 3706'

. I tried

```
myDSN="Driver=Oracle in OraDb11g_home1;DSN=111.111.111.11:1111/orcl;USER ID=xxxx;PASSWORD=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True"
```

it did not help either and gave a 'run time error -2147467259(80004005)'

Can anyone help please?

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you lookup the error ? What is it?

Comment: The connectionstring is not valid, have a look at http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForOracleFromOracle or https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/

Comment: The second connectionstring looks like ODBC (see https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/)

Comment: error 3706 says the provider cannot be found.

Comment: Did you install the Oracle oledb provider? You can download it from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, no, do I need to install this on my local machine or the remote server?

Comment: On your local computer

Comment: ok, i had both instantclient-basic and instantclient-odbc installed, environment variables set, and I added in ODBC64bit a new data source with Oracle in instantclient_11_2 as driver. The connection was tested as a success. But when I was trying to create a link in Access via ODBC with the same drive, it said ' [Microsoft ODBC driver] in this DSN driver does not match with application'.

Comment: And I have also tried to add a driver in Access Microsoft ODBC for Oracle, this error message popped up 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle (0x80004005) Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation. Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSNs are user-created text/xml scripts with specific connection settings to avoid writing them directly in code. Usually DSNs are used for ODBC not OLEDB connections. Oracle I believe uses TNS aliases.

Currently, in both your attempts you do not assign a named DSN file but assign it to a server/host name. Your overall issue can be as easy as replacing *DSN* for *Data Source* or *DBQ*. Notice too user and password named arguments differ.

```vb
' OLEDB
myDSN = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=111.111.111.11:1521/orcl;" _
         & "USER ID=xxxx;PASSWORD=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True"

' ODBC
myDSN = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=111.111.111.11:1521/orcl;" _
         & "UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True"
```

And for TNS alias connections where below *My_OraDB* alias is defined in the [`tnsnames.ora`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF271) file.

```vb
' OLEDB
myDSN = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=My_OraDB" _
         & "USER ID=xxxx;PASSWORD=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True"

' ODBC
myDSN = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=My_OraDB;" _
         & "UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True"
```

Alternatively, after creating a named DSN where *Driver* and *DBQ* parameters are not specified:

```vb
' ODBC
myDSN = "DSN=My_DSN;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx"
```

Be sure ODBC driver aligns to your application bit type. You can build the specific DSN via odbcad32.exe located in 32-bit (C\windows\sysWOW64) or 64-bit (C:\Windows\System32).

Comment: It's vice versa: `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` is 64bit, `C\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` is 32bit! Yes it is confusing, but that's how it is.

Comment: `111.111.111.11:1521/orcl` is called "EZCONNECT", resp. "Easy Connect". It must be enabled on your database, it may not work in your case.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ... thanks for that note and let's await our OP for confirmation.

Comment: I tried OLEDB and it gave me error 3706. I tried ODBC and it gave me error -2147467259(80004005)' as I said above.

Comment: I checked tnsnames.ora file and this is how it looks ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = xxxxxxx))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = xxxxxxx)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
Does this look alright?

Comment: I tried to connect it in R and it worked well with following codes,library(DBI);library(ROracle)
ConString<-"(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =xxxxxxx)(PORT =1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = 64oracle) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))"
drv<-dbDriver("Oracle")
con<-dbConnect(drv,username = "xxxxx", password = "xxxxx", dbname = ConString)

Comment: And this is how ODBC configured. Really having no clue now. USER DSN
name: 64oracle
driver: Oracle in OraDb11g_home1

Oracle ODBC driver configuration
Data Source Name:64oracle
Description:XXXX
TNS Service Name: ORCL
User ID:XXXX

Comment: You may not have the required Oracle OLDEB and ODBC Driver installed prior to attempting in VBA. Check odbcad32.exe for ODBC and your registry keys for OLEDB. Download from Oracle as needed. In R, you are not using `RODBC` but `ROracle` module which handles the interfacing differently and does not require additional installations.

Comment: It worked out. You need to install on your local machine instantclient basic and instantclient ODBC packages that matches your oracle database version. Then you can set up an ODBC connection. And make sure your Access and Oracle database have the same bit type :)

Comment: Excellent! Indeed, those installs no doubt included needed providers and drivers for the OLEDB or ODBC connections.